# Can i use For Loop to give differrent result/value?

Tags: c#

Example Code(Is Wrong but a reference):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if ((i % 3) == 0 )
    {
         Console.WriteLine(i+":x");
    }
    else if ((i % 2) == 0 
    {
         Console.WriteLine(i+":y");
    }
    else 
    {
         Console.WriteLine(i+":z");
    }
}
```

Result I Want:

```
1:x
2:y
3:z
4:x
5:y
6:z
7:x
8:y
9:z
10:x
```

Comment: Yes, you can definitely do that - although you'll need to fix up a few bits of your current code. It's hard to tell what you're really asking here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want...

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
        if ((i % 3) == 1)
        {
         Console.WriteLine(i+":x");
        }
        else if ((i % 3) == 2)
        {
         Console.WriteLine(i+":y");
        }
        else //if ((i % 3) == 0)
        {
         Console.WriteLine(i+":z");
        }
}
```

or less complicatedly...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    switch (i%3)
    {
    case 0:
      Console.WriteLine(i+":z");
      break;
    case 1:
      Console.WriteLine(i+":x");
      break;
    case 2:
      Console.WriteLine(i+":y");
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: yea that what i want Thankz! Matt

Comment: Note that these examples will start with 0 and end with 9, also the first code example here has the same flaw as the original code in your question, the second writeline call is missing the index variable, so the code is not legal.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Lasse - I've fixed it as suggested - and upvoted your answer as it was more complete than mine.

Answer (score 3):

```
switch (i%3)
{
case 0: // :z
case 1: // :x
case 2: // :y
}
```

Comment: Thankz Marcelo!! It useful for me.

Answer (score 2):

The important part here is not to change the number you're calculating the modulus against.

In other words, instead of checking if `i % 3 == 0` and then `i % 2 == 0`, check if:

- `i % 3 == 0` --> x
- `i % 3 == 1` --> y
- `i % 3 == 2` --> z

There are many ways to do what you want:

***Hint**: to test any of these, you can use [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net), simply copy and paste one of the above code examples and hit F5 to run and you'll see that the output matches what you wanted.*

### With an array:

```
void Main()
{
    string[] letters = new[] { "x", "y", "z" };
    for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((index + 1) + ":" + letters[index % 3]);
    }
}
```

### With a switch/case

```
void Main()
{
    for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++)
    {
        switch (index % 3)
        {
            case 0:
                Console.WriteLine((index + 1) + ":x");
                break;
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine((index + 1) + ":y");
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine((index + 1) + ":z");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

### With if-statements

```
void Main()
{
    for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++)
    {
        if (index % 3 == 0)
            Console.WriteLine((index + 1) + ":x");
        else if (index % 3 == 1)
            Console.WriteLine((index + 1) + ":y");
        else
            Console.WriteLine((index + 1) + ":z");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var d = new Dictionary<int,string> { {1,"x"}, {2,"y"}, {0,"z"} };
    for(int i = 1; i<= 10; i++)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", i, d[i%3]);
```